# SQLite: Table X has no column named Y

Tags: android, sqlite

I've read a lot of threads/questions here about the problem stated above, but no solution seemed to work for me. Here is my database creation:

```
  public static final String TABLE_CARDS = "cards";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION = "question";
  public static final String COLUMN_ANSWER = "answer";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "cards.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_CARDS + "(" 
      + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
      + COLUMN_QUESTION + " text not null, " 
      + COLUMN_ANSWER + " text not null);";
```

Here I pass a new object to the database:

```
 public Card createCard(String question, String answer) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_QUESTION, question);
    values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ANSWER, answer);

    long insertId = database.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CARDS, null,
        values); 

    Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_CARDS,
        allColumns, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = " + insertId, null,
        null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();


    Card newCard = cursorToCard(cursor);
    cursor.close();
    return newCard;
  }
```

EDIT:

The error message:

```
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796): Error inserting answer=testanw question=testqu
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table cards has no column named answer (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO cards(answer,question) VALUES (?,?)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
10-12 07:07:55.503: E/SQLiteDatabase(796):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
```

And the problem is that as soon as i want to write into the database it throws this error. I want to store a String named question and answer in my cards-database. Sorry for missing these informations!!

Comment: Could you post the error message?

Comment: "the problem stated above" ... above what?

Comment: @Bhushan aahh... - anyway - as mentioned the error message and a brief explanation of what was expected would get us a long way ;-)

Comment: Uninstall and reinstall your app, or click Clear Data on its entry in Settings.

Comment: hi, I added some informations. Do you need more information?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uninstall your app and install it again. You may have created this table before and this column didn't exist in the earlier version of your app.

When you add a column and don't use `onUpdate` method, existing tables don't have the new column added. This is not to say that you should use `onUpdate` every time you change your schema during development- `onUpdate` should be used when you actually release a new version of your app.

Comment: Thank you! Reinstalling of the app fixed it. I was missing a Space in the SQL-Statement which creates the table, found that bug and fixed it. But I did not reinstall. Thank you!

Comment: @Szymon re installing app solved my problem. Thank you.

Comment: "Uninstall your app and install it again" is work for me... but in iOS and swift 3. No matter what platforms you are...this solution works anyway

Answer (score 0):

when you are not using onUpdate() method then Just change the name of your database everytime  whenever you add a new column in the table .